# Do we need to specify compression level when extracting a compressed tar file?

Tags: linux, macos, gzip, tar, bzip2

From my tests so far on OSX 10.8 and CentOS 5.5, it looks like `tar` automatically deduces the compression type of an archive, i.e., I could do `tar -xf <compressed archive>` instead of doing `tar -jxf <bzip2 compressed archive>` or `tar -zxf <gzip compressed archive>`.

I would like to know if I can depend on this automatic compression detection feature of tar, or is this feature new?

These are the tar versions I played with.

OSX 10.8 -- bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3

CentOs 5.5 -- tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1

Thanks,

Comment: how this question fits this board?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question, and is therefore [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It might be appropriate at [Unix.SE] or [SU].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that modern gnu-tar is able to auto-detect all compression types, as mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/107976/39599). So to answer your question, no you don't have to specify type, and yes `tar -xf` will always work fine.